# GCC 4.9.1 ThreadSanitizer "As if synchronized via sleep"

Tags: multithreading, c++11, gcc4.9, thread-sanitizer

I'm working on cleaning up ThreadSanitizer warnings in a largeish project. In particular in this exact case, there is a spawned thread which reads from a file, producer. Then there are one or more decompression threads as part of a thread pool. Finally, there is one thread which actually does processing by retrieving the decompressed blocks. This of course allows simultaneous decompression of multiple blocks.

There are many locations where the project synchronizes via an atomic bool and `usleep()`, including this one in particular. This is, of course, not ideal and is one of the things which was assigned to me.

But as long as mutexes and locks are represented, I don't see what the issue is that ThreadSanitizer would complain about (other than potentially reduced efficiency compared to using a condition_variable).

ThreadSanitizer complains about data races "As if synchronized via sleep", and providing a location of where `usleep()` is called. My issue is that of course synchronizing via sleep isn't ideal, but I don't see a data race as long as mutexes are respected. As best as I understand the way mutexes work, I do believe they are respected.

So I'm trying to create a minimal set of reproduction steps in order to identify exactly what it is which ThreadSanitizer is complaining about.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
// g++ --std=c++11 -lpthread as-if-synchronized-via-sleep.cpp -g -fsanitize=thread -pie -fPIC
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <unistd.h>

class Data {
public:
        char uncompressed[1024];
        char compressed[1024];
        std::atomic<bool> done = {false};
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        std::atomic<bool> done = {false};
        std::atomic<int> count = {0};

        std::mutex m;
        std::vector<Data*> v;

        std::thread provider{[&](){
                while ( not done ) {
                        while ( 100 < count ) {
                                usleep(20);
                                if ( done ) {
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                        Data *data = new Data();
                        // Simulate reading in compressed data
                        for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data->uncompressed); ++i )
                                data->uncompressed[i] = char(rand());
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
                        v.push_back(data);
                        l.unlock();
                        ++count;
                }
                return;
        }};

        std::thread decompressor{[&](){
                while ( not done ) {
                        while ( 0 == count ) {
                                usleep(20);
                                if ( done ) {
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
                        if ( v.empty() ) {
                                continue;
                        }
                        Data* data = v.front();
                        // Simulate decompressing it.
                        for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data->compressed); ++i )
                                data->compressed[i] = data->uncompressed[i] ^ char(0xff);
                        data->done = true;
                }
        }};

        std::thread consumer{[&](){
                while ( not done ) {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
                        while ( not v.empty() ) {
                                if ( done ) {
                                        break;
                                }
                                if ( v.front()->done ) {
                                        break;
                                }
                                l.unlock();
                                usleep(20);
                                l.lock();
                        }
                        if ( done ) {
                                break;
                        }
                        // Simulate consuming it
                        Data* data = v.front();
                        v.erase(v.begin());
                        l.unlock();
                        // Pretend we're doing stuff with decompressed data
                        std::vector<char> vv(1,1);
                        for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data->uncompressed); ++i ) {
                                if ( data->uncompressed[i] )
                                        vv.back() += data->uncompressed[i];
                                else
                                        vv.emplace_back();
                        }
                        delete data;
                        size_t n = 0;
                        for ( auto c : vv ) {
                                std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << (int)c;
                        }
                }
        }};
        std::cout << "Main sleeping" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        done = true;
        std::cout << "Main joining..." << std::endl;
        provider.join();
        decompressor.join();
        consumer.join();

        std::cout << "Cleaning up" << std::endl;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
        while ( not v.empty() ) {
                delete v.back();
                v.erase(std::next(v.rbegin()).base());
        }

        std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

With that code compiled as the first comment indicates, using GCC 4.9.1, I get the following message from ThreadSanitizer at the end of execution:

```
Main sleeping
4f72ffffffa8ffffffb9Main joining...
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=64255)
  Write of size 8 at 0x7d100000dfc8 by thread T3:
    #0 operator delete(void*) /home/keithb/dev/gcc/gcc_4_9_1_release/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:592 (libtsan.so.0+0x000000049480)
    #1 deallocate /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/ext/new_allocator.h:110 (a.out+0x000000004ec9)
    #2 deallocate /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/alloc_traits.h:383 (a.out+0x000000004b98)
    #3 _M_destroy /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:535 (a.out+0x000000005fbc)
    #4 std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() /home/keithb/dev/gcc/gcc_4_9_1_build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:166 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5b30)
    #5 ~__shared_count /home/keithb/dev/gcc/gcc_4_9_1_build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:666 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5b30)
    #6 ~__shared_ptr /home/keithb/dev/gcc/gcc_4_9_1_build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:914 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5b30)
    #7 ~shared_ptr /home/keithb/dev/gcc/gcc_4_9_1_build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr.h:93 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5b30)
    #8 execute_native_thread_routine /home/keithb/dev/gcc/gcc_4_9_1_release/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:95 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5b30)

  Previous atomic write of size 4 at 0x7d100000dfc8 by main thread:
    #0 __tsan_atomic32_fetch_add /home/keithb/dev/gcc/gcc_4_9_1_release/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interface_atomic.cc:468 (libtsan.so.0+0x0000000206ce)
    #1 __exchange_and_add /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/ext/atomicity.h:49 (a.out+0x0000000021f4)
    #2 __exchange_and_add_dispatch /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/ext/atomicity.h:82 (a.out+0x0000000022ab)
    #3 std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:146 (a.out+0x000000007e99)
    #4 std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:666 (a.out+0x000000007346)
    #5 std::__shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:914 (a.out+0x000000007019)
    #6 std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>::~shared_ptr() /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/shared_ptr.h:93 (a.out+0x000000007045)
    #7 thread<main(int, char**)::<lambda()> > /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/thread:135 (a.out+0x0000000031eb)
    #8 main /home/keithb/dev/mytest/thread-sanitizer-checks/main.cpp:102 (a.out+0x000000002bc9)

  Location is heap block of size 64 at 0x7d100000dfc0 allocated by main thread:
    #0 operator new(unsigned long) /home/keithb/dev/gcc/gcc_4_9_1_release/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:560 (libtsan.so.0+0x0000000496c2)
    #1 allocate /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/ext/new_allocator.h:104 (a.out+0x000000004e28)
    #2 allocate /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/alloc_traits.h:357 (a.out+0x000000004aed)
    #3 __shared_count<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> > /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:616 (a.out+0x000000004735)
    #4 __shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> > /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1090 (a.out+0x00000000443f)
    #5 shared_ptr<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> > /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/shared_ptr.h:316 (a.out+0x00000000425f)
    #6 allocate_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> > >, std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> > /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/shared_ptr.h:588 (a.out+0x000000004118)
    #7 make_shared<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> >, std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> > /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/shared_ptr.h:604 (a.out+0x000000003e74)
    #8 _M_make_routine<std::_Bind_simple<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()> > /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/thread:193 (a.out+0x000000003925)
    #9 thread<main(int, char**)::<lambda()> > /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/thread:135 (a.out+0x0000000031b9)
    #10 main /home/keithb/dev/mytest/thread-sanitizer-checks/main.cpp:102 (a.out+0x000000002bc9)

  Thread T3 (tid=64259, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create /home/keithb/dev/gcc/gcc_4_9_1_release/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:877 (libtsan.so.0+0x000000047bf3)
    #1 __gthread_create /home/keithb/dev/gcc/gcc_4_9_1_build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:662 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5be0)
    #2 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) /home/keithb/dev/gcc/gcc_4_9_1_release/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:142 (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b5be0)
    #3 main /home/keithb/dev/mytest/thread-sanitizer-checks/main.cpp:102 (a.out+0x000000002bc9)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /home/keithb/include/c++/4.9.1/ext/new_allocator.h:110 deallocate
==================
Cleaning up
Done!
ThreadSanitizer: reported 1 warnings
```

After all threads have been joined, tsan finally complains about "As if synchronized via sleep", in what appears to be the destructor of a lambda, specifically a shared pointer. As that's a c++11 feature and google has provided plenty of evidence that ThreadSanitizer doesn't like C++11 very well, I suspect that's not a "real" race per se.

Although... the fact that the lambda is used as the entrypoint to a thread... I do wonder if that's an actual race wherein the thread hasn't *quite* exited before the lamda is being destroyed? That would be in the arena of a compiler bug so I don't care to investigate much further (scope creep et al).

So my questions (I know they're somewhat open-ended, please help me to narrow them down?)

Why would ThreadSanitizer not detect a data race "as if synchronized via sleep" in producer, decompressor, and consumer in this case? And, moreover, would it be possible (and can you provide examples) to modify this code to...

A) ...produce a true data race which emits a ThreadSanitizer warning which does not "typically" cause crashes (current production release of the software in question does not appear to crash as a result of this supposed data race)?

B) ...produce a true data race which doesn't *appear* to be a data race on first glance, but knowledge and/or experience reveals otherwise?

C) ...produce a false positive from ThreadSanitizer but not actually have a data race.

Comment: Did you find anything about this issue?

Comment: Too bad. I found your question because we were experiencing a false positive data race at my company after adding a -g flag to gcc. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719796/gcc-thread-sanitizer-false-positive-only-for-debug-info-flag) is the question just in case it is related to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that ThreadSanitizer is seeing the sleeps and it is warning you that the pattern it is detecting is commonly seen when synchronization is performed using sleeps instead of using mutexes or condition variables. See https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerReportFormat

You should move your code to using condition variables.